# Find all $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $y \in \mathbb N$ such that $x^2-y!=2001$ and prove your answer is correct

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, diophantine-equations

I have the following question:

> Find all $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $y \in \mathbb N$ such that $x^2-y!=2001$. Prove that your answer is correct.

And I have absolutely no idea where to even start. I don't even know what my end going is going to be here. What do I have to do first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For large enough $y$, $y!$ will be divisible by $9$ and
then $x^2=y!+2001\equiv3\pmod 9$ which is impossible. How large, is large
enough?

Comment: Why is $x^2 \equiv 3$ (mod 9) impossible?

Comment: @MarkDodds You could check all values of $x$ modulo $9$.

Answer (score 0):

By trial of the first $5$ values for $y$

$$(y,x)=(4,\pm45)$$

For $x>5$, see previous answer.

Comment: Actually, you missed $(y, x) = (4, -45)$ since we have $x \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: @MaxLi Thank you for spotting that, I've corrected my typo and up-voted your comment.